# Oracle: Select multiple values from a column while satisfying condition for some values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column COL in a table which has integer values like: 1, 2, 3, 10, 11 ... and son on. Uniqueness in the table is created by an ID. Each ID can be associated with multiple COL values. For example

```
 ID | COL
——————————
  1 |  2   
————+—————
  1 |  3   
————+—————
  1 | 10  
————+—————
```

is valid.

What I want to do is select only the COL values from the table that are greater than 3, AND (the problematic part) also select the value that is the MAX of 1, 2, and 3, if they exist at all. So in the table above, I would want to select values [3, 10] because 10 is greater than 3 and 3 = MAX(3, 2).

I know I can do this with two SQL statements, but it's sort of messy. Is there a way of doing it with one statement only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT col FROM table
WHERE
    col > 3
UNION
SELECT MAX(col) FROM table
WHERE
    col <= 3
```

This query does not assume you want the results per id, because you don't explicitely mention it.
I don't think you need pl/sql for this, SQL is enough.